# Select definite rows in Impala

Tags: limit, impala, row-number, rownum

Let's say, that I need to select rows from 3 to 10.
For MySQL I would use **limit**
For ORACLE I would use **rownum**

Does Impala allow to select definite rows via such simple method?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: You should read the Impala documentation. It's free. http://www.cloudera.com/documentation/enterprise/latest/topics/impala_limit.html

Comment: I didn't find the solution first time. However now it is clear for me. Thank you =)

Comment: If somebody has this question - the solution is combination of LIMIT and OFFSET.

Comment: Thanks @AnastasiaVitchenko, you should add an official answer to this question so we  can upvote it.

Answer (score 0):

Use the [`OFFSET`](https://docs.cloudera.com/documentation/enterprise/latest/topics/impala_offset.html) clause.

For example:

```
SELECT ... 
FROM ... 
ORDER BY ...
LIMIT 10 OFFSET 5
```

This would select 10 rows beginning with the 6th row. The offset is 0-based so `OFFSET 0` would start from the first row. You need to use `ORDER BY` when using the `OFFSET` clause.

Note however if you are using this for pagination, it is not recommended to do this unless required for backwards compatibility. From the [documentation](https://docs.cloudera.com/documentation/enterprise/latest/topics/impala_offset.html):

> Because Impala queries typically involve substantial amounts of I/O, use this technique only for compatibility in cases where you cannot rewrite the application logic. For best performance and scalability, wherever practical, query as many items as you expect to need, cache them on the application side, and display small groups of results to users using application logic.